# I need to find the values that are local minimums in this array, but I'm getting an arrayindexoutofbounds exception. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode, minimum

```
public class LocalMinimum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {8, 5, 7, 2, 3, 0, 1, 9};
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
            int prevValue = A[i - 1];
            int nextValue = A[i + 1];
            if ((A[i] < prevValue) && (A[i] < nextValue)) {
                System.out.println(A[i] + " is a minimum value.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(A[i] + " is not a minimum value.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: Iterate to `A.length - 1`. Right now, you try to do `A[i + 1]` which would be out of bounds because you currently iterate to `A.length`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error message though because it'll be out of bounds from A[i - 1]

Comment: Yeah I did that and got the code to work, but I just wanted to print out the first and last value too. Thanks for the quick responses though

Answer (score 1):

You should use module when trying to access A's itens so it never is out of bounds.

like:

```
int prevValue = A[((i - 1) % A.length)];
int nextValue = A[((i + 1) % A.length)];
```

This way, the result for the first iteration for prevValue will be the last number instead and the result for the last iteration for nextValue will be the first number.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing

```
int prevValue = A[i - 1];
int nextValue = A[i + 1];
```

in the for loop, starting from `i = 0` and ending with `i = array.length - 1`, be aware that at the first and last turn, you will be trying to get values from `array[-1]` and `array[array.length]` elements, which do not exist. Try starting the loop from `1` to `array.length - 2`:

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.length - 2; i++) {
    // do your job
}
```